# flash player or silver light?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i want to create a help video and put theme on my web site.
i did some search i internet to find whats the best way to do it.
use flash player or use Microsoft silver light technology to do this?

what s the best open source video player for my case?

my site is on mvc3 razor on .net4.0
and my video are in .wvm format off course i can convert theme 
to any other format

please guide me which one of them is better and have advantage rather than other?

thanks all

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be to use neither and use HTML 5 and the [Video](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) element.

Flash and Silverlight are becoming deprecated technologies for Web UI's now.

You could use third party libraries such as [modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) to detect the browser capabilities and respond accordingly.

This [page](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-Browser-Polyfills) contains cross-browser polyfills, search the page for Video